# InnoSetup tries to Create DefaultDir in any case

Tags: inno-setup

I created an installer with innosetup to install an application that consists of two executables. Each of them should go to a separate folder.  So I created a custom InputDirPage using the "CreateInputDirPage" function and added two entries to this page, one for each executable 
To prevent the default DirPage from showing up I used these parameters in the [Setup} section:

`DisableDirPage = yes` AND `AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage= no`

I wrote functions to extract the Folder paths from my custom DirPage and 
this works fine and evrything ends up where it is supposed to be.

BUT: During the installation process Innosetup tries to create the folder set in the DefaultDirName as this  folder is the value in the invisible DirPage. 
If that folder does not exists and one would need administrator rights to create that folder, the setup will crash.

I worked around that problem by setting `DefaultDirName = {pf}` in the [Setup] section.
(As the program folder does always exist, I do not get any error messsage for failed  creation attempts that way)

Now my questions are these:

1. Is there a setup parameter that tells Innosetup to completely ignore
   the content of the wizard dir page? Because making it invisble seems
   no to be sufficient.
2. Can I set that content or the `{app}` constant at runtime to avoid the "DefaultDirName" folder from being created?

Comment: Yes, there is: `CreateAppDir=False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an option called [CreateAppDir](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_createappdir.htm).

```
[Setup]
CreateAppDir=No
```

Comment: Thanks, RobeN : It worked.   And sorry for the delay in my answer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what it does?

Comment: As documentation linked explains, you may want to use that option in order not to create AppDir during the installation process. You can use that for example if you want to update or install plugin/mod to existing application or when you set and create app directory in a different way as Bachi did.